# Add row to UITableView crash if initially empty table

Tags: uitableview, row, addition

I'm using the code below to refresh a tableview which I just added a row into. The code works for adding a row to the table if there is at least 1 row already in the table. However, it crashes if it was initially an empty table.

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[commentsArray count] inSection:0], nil];

[commentsTableView beginUpdates];

[commentsArray addObject:newestEntry];
[commentsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

[commentsTableView endUpdates];

[commentsTableView scrollToBottom:YES];
```

The crash response I get is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error is telling you the when UIKit calls `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is returning `0` both before and after your updates. So either you have an error in that method or in your update. You said in comment to a previous answer that your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is correct, then it must be the update. If `commentsArray` is nil in the first update for some reason that might explain things. Perhaps try the following:

```
NSAssert(commentsArray, @"commentsArray is nil");
[commentsArray addObject:newestEntry];
```

The assert will be ignored in a release build, so use a debug build.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU. It turns out my array wasn't even alloced when the HTTP Request responds with an empty string! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I dislike the fact that Objective-C allows you do stuff with nil without complaining, so after getting bitten a few times I got into the habit of using NSAssert anywhere that a nil object would bite me. I'm getting bitten a lot less lately ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the array which you are using to update is the same as Array which you are using while reloading the Table.

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [commentsArray count];
}
```

If this couldn't solve your problem, please put some code over here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure what other code I should post to clarify this.. My `numberOfRowsInSection` is correct. I'm actually making a POST request using `ASIHTTPRequest`, and the above code block is called in the success response delegate method. The flow is that I post a comment using POST, then when it returns a success, I reparse the feed, add the new comment `newestEntry` to `commentsArray`, then update `commentsTableView`.